# Specifying jQuery Alias in Script#

Tags: jquery, script#

Is there a way to specify the jQuery alias Script# uses when generating JavaScript? For example, if we expect our version of jQuery as “$myJQuery” using noConflict(true), is there a way to get Script# to compile all references to "$myJQuery" instead of "jQuery" when loading the generated script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to recompile the jQuery import library.

You can do so by downloading the source code at https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp, then modifying [jQuery.cs](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/master/src/Libraries/jQuery/jQuery.Core/jQuery.cs) so that `[ScriptName("$")]` becomes `[ScriptName("$myJQuery")]`.

Once recompiled, drop the jQuery dll into your Script# project folder and re-add the jQuery reference using your new dll instead of the stock dll.

Comment: It also seems like a good workaround is to put a script literal in a static constructor, such as:

`static public class Startup
    {
        static Startup()
        {
            Script.Literal("$ = $myJQuery;");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to branch the Script# source, a good workaround is to just manually set the local alias to your overridden one in a static constructor:

```
static public class Startup
{
    static Startup()
    { 
        Script.Literal("$ = $myJQuery;"); 
    }
}
```

If you're using jQuery in any static constructors, be aware of the order of their generation in the final script.